# common login code in meteor

Tags: angular, meteor

i have a piece of code in meteor that adds a customer object to the session.
how do i make it a common code so that i can call it for normal login/fb login/twitter etc?
i'm using angularjs2/meteor

```
MeteorObservable.call('getCustomer', Meteor.user().emails[0].address).subscribe((cust: Cust) => 
                            {
                                Session.set('session_cust',cust);
                                this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
                            }, (error) => 
                            {
                                console.log('session cust error');
                            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Injectable()
@InjectUser('user')
export class CustLoginService
{
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    handleLogin(): void 
    {
        if (Meteor.userId()) 
        {
            MeteorObservable.call('getCustomer', Meteor.user().emails[0].address).subscribe((cust: Cust) => 
            {
                if (cust)
                {
                    Session.set('session_cust', cust);
                    this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('Not a customer');
                    this.router.navigate(['/zone-list']);
                }

            }, (error) => 
                {
                    console.log('session cust error');
                });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('no meteor user id');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Tracker.autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun) to watch for a user logging in, independent of path:

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  if ( Meteor.user() ){
    ... your code - will only run when the user logs in
  }
});
```